# run mp3 and .aac vlc audio in java

Tags: java, audio, netbeans-8

I would like to run audio file from java and i read many codes in SO but unbale to run my file perhaps! 
Seems I have mentioned wrong path or using wrong lib .
Please assist me what's wrong in below code to run mp3 or VLC .aac format file

```
  public void playSound() {
  try {
      AudioInputStream audioInputStream =  AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File("D:/clinic/clinic/mysound.mp3").getAbsoluteFile());
     Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
    clip.open(audioInputStream);
    clip.start();
 } catch(Exception ex) {
    System.out.println("Error with playing sound.");
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

Comment: Please post what error are you facing ?

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the this.getClass.getResource() method instead of the File(file) method, maybe it would work. Remember that the file that the audio is in has to be in the same package as the class that is running it. If this doesn't work, then try it with a .wav file(you can use a .mp3 to .wav converter).

```
public void run() {
    try {
        AudioInputStream audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(this.getClass().getResource("mysound.mp3"));
        Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
        clip.open(audioInputStream);
        clip.start();
        clip.loop(Clip.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

[`AudioSystem`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/AudioSystem.html#getAudioFileTypes()) does not support .mp3 files. (Only AIFC, AIFF, AU, SND, and WAVE)

If you want to use .mp3 files, try using [`MediaPlayer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/media/MediaPlayer.html) instead.

```
// Fake init of JFX Toolkit (Just do this once before you use MediaPlayer) 
// Not needed in a JavaFX application as Application.launch() inits the toolkit 
new JFXPanel();  


Media media = new Media(new File("yourFile.mp3").toURI().toString());   
MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer(media);    
player.play();
```

Answer (score 0):

The audioformats supported natively are nit that useful if you don't want to have huge audiofiles.
I ended using WAV files as it was what I could get to work, but it bothered me all the time.

Using [jaad](http://jaadec.sourceforge.net) was trickier than I thought, but I got it working now: [Java play AAC encoded audio](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45660234/7365927)