# play AAC with JAAD from Webstream

Tags: java, aac

I need to play AAC encoded audio with my Java application.
I read [Java play AAC encoded audio ( JAAD decoder )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45660234/java-play-aac-encoded-audio-jaad-decoder) which shows how to play an array of files.
But how do i play AAC when my source is a webstream?

Comment: I  tried to do this couple of years ago, and back then JAAD had troubles with AAC+ format. Maybe author fixed that. Anyway - reading from files means reading from filestream. Reading from web will mean reading from some other stream. For JAAD does not matter. Stream is a stream.

Comment: how to pass a urlStream to the decoder ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution to play raw AAC with JAAD:

```
public class AACPlayer extends AbstractPlayer implements Runnable {
private Thread runnerThread;
@Override
public void stop() {
    stop = true;
    GUIHandler.getInstance().resetComponents();
}

@Override
public void play() {
    stop = false;
    if(!runnerThread.isAlive()) {
        runnerThread = new Thread(this);
        runnerThread.start();
    }
}

@Override
public void setUrl(URL url) {
    this.url = url;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    decodeAndPlayAAC();
}

private void decodeAndPlayAAC() {
    SourceDataLine line = null;
    byte[] b;
    try {
        isPlaying = true;
        final ADTSDemultiplexer adts = new ADTSDemultiplexer(url.openStream());
        final Decoder dec = new Decoder(adts.getDecoderSpecificInfo());
        final SampleBuffer buf = new SampleBuffer();
        while(!stop) {
            b = adts.readNextFrame();
            dec.decodeFrame(b, buf);

            if(line==null) {
                final AudioFormat aufmt = new AudioFormat(buf.getSampleRate(), buf.getBitsPerSample(), buf.getChannels(), true, true);
                line = AudioSystem.getSourceDataLine(aufmt);
                line.open();
                line.start();
            }
            b = buf.getData();
            line.write(b, 0, b.length);
        }
    } catch (LineUnavailableException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (AACException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if(line!=null) {
            line.stop();
            line.close();
            isPlaying = false;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Do you know why a stream might be stuttering with this method?

Comment: Have you tried inceasing the buffer?

Answer (score 0):

From the example you have gave, it uses `MP4Container`.

From `JAAD`'scode:

```
public MP4Container(InputStream in) throws IOException {
    this.in = new MP4InputStream(in);
    boxes = new ArrayList<Box>();

    readContent();
}

public MP4Container(RandomAccessFile in) throws IOException {
    this.in = new MP4InputStream(in);
    boxes = new ArrayList<Box>();

    readContent();
}
```

Example uses  `MP4Container(RandomAccessFile in)` constructor while you will have to use this  `MP4Container(InputStream in)` where `in` will be input stream from socket.

Comment: did that like above