# How to play audio in Kotlin Multiplatform (Desktop)?

Tags: kotlin, desktop-application, kotlin-multiplatform

Currently I am Building a project using Kotlin Multiplatform. This project is only for Android and Desktop.

I want to play a audio file in this project.Can anyone help how can I do this? OR can anyone share some libraries that can do this task

Answer (score 1):

The first question is what audio formats you want to support (WAV, MP3, OGG, AAC etc.). The second one is licensing of used library (MIT, GPL etc.). More questions can be about if sound file is local file, streamed from network etc.

In general you can try your luck with Korge (JVM, Android etc. platforms) and it's [audio library](https://docs.korge.org/audio/). Afaik now only library with KMP support for now.

If Korge is not working for you, you have to implement each platform separately.

The best solution for Android is [ExoPlayer](https://developer.android.com/media/implement/playback-app) which supports many audio formats.

For desktop is situation more complicated because of licencing and other issues.

If you want play just WAV files, you can you use Clip and SourceDataLine from javax.sound.sampled package. Basic tutorial is [here](https://www.baeldung.com/java-play-sound).

For MP3 and more formats you need to use for example [JavaFX Library](https://github.com/openjdk/jfx) ([Gradle version](https://github.com/openjfx/javafx-gradle-plugin#getting-started)) or [JLayer Library](https://github.com/umjammer/jlayer).

For ACC you can try [JAAD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45660234/java-play-aac-encoded-audio-jaad-decoder).

For OGG you can try [jcraft](http://www.jcraft.com/jorbis/) or [j-ogg-all](https://github.com/stephengold/j-ogg-all) (Gradle support).

This [music player](https://github.com/SEAbdulbasit/MusicApp-KMP) can be also used as example. It's using Exoplayer for Android and [vlcj framework](https://github.com/caprica/vlcj) for desktop (under GPL licence).

Some minimal MP3 implementation can be found [here](https://github.com/delthas/JavaMP3).

As mentioned before many of these libraries are under GPL licence so using it in "commercial closed sourced software" can mean buying licence or doing other steps.

Answer (score 0):

on desktop you should use javax.sound and in android some native android audio api